# control + s, return false but still call another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
        function_which_does_a_lot_including_ajax_calls();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I'm trying to call a method on <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and, the call to `function_which_does_a_lot_including_ajax_calls()` stops the code from reaching the "return false" in time, which means that the browser prompts the default "Do you want to save this website" window.

If I change it to simply:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
        // function_which_does_a_lot_including_ajax_calls();
        return false;
    }
});
```

... the return false is triggered, and nothing happens (no default prompt).

Is there a way I can do a lot of stuff, but still return false so that the browser does not do its default behavior?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's a little strange that there's some kind of "timeout" involved with a keydown callback... Are you sure the function isn't aborting due to an exception inside `function_which_does_a_lot_including_ajax_calls`?

Comment: the `function_which_does_a_lot_including_ajax_calls` even has a prompt in it, so maybe that's an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the behaviour you described but you can try something like:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
        setTimeout(function_which_does_a_lot_including_ajax_calls, 100);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevents browser's default behaviour (similar to `return false`).

Example:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (condition_says_NO_to_default) {
        e.preventDefault();
        .... //Rest of code
```

Update: Alternative method. The code below maintains the scope, `this`  and event object reference, while the `return false` statement is processed first:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var $this = this; //Save reference for later
    setTimeout(function(){
        (function(event){
            //Your code here
        }).call($this, e);
    }, 1); // An extremely low timeout.
    return false;
});
```

Comment: for whatever reason, e.preventDefault() is not preventing the default browser behavior.  I'm still getting a prompt or saving the website, which is default browser for Ctrl + S.

Comment: Alternatively, you can wrap the code in a `setTimeout`, as shown in my updated answer. The suggested code also correctly deals with `this`.

Comment: I find the "preventDefault" solution cleaner but I think there's a trick to make it work with every browser.